# Custom NSTextView border issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, nstextview

I want to make NSTextView dot border, my drawRect: code is below

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    CGFloat lineDash[2];

    lineDash[0] = 1.0;
    lineDash[1] = 1.0;

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    [path setLineDash:lineDash count:2 phase:0.0];
    [path stroke];
}
```

I alse want to give some margin between text and border, my code is below

```
[textView setTextContainerInset:NSMakeSize(0, 10.0)];
[textView setString:@"This is a testThis is a testThis is a testThis is a test"];
```

But the result is that the top border is missing, who knows how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Maybe `[super drawRect:dirtyRect]` is setting up a clipping rect, so I would try `[path setClip]` just before `[path stroke]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subclass `NSScrollView` instead of `NSTextView`. And then you will have a good performance. It can be done like this:

**NSScrollView subclass:**

```
-(void)tile {
    id contentView = [self contentView];
    [super tile];
    [contentView setFrame:NSInsetRect([contentView frame], 1.0, 1.0)];
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    CGFloat lineDash[2];

    lineDash[0] = 1.5;
    lineDash[1] = 1.5;

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    [path setLineDash:lineDash count:2 phase:0.0];
    [path setLineWidth:2];
    [path stroke];
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot image]

Comment: It's a way to solve the problem, but I didn't put my NSTextView over a NSScrollView, so use [path setClip] before [path stroke] is better. Thanks!